# How do I remove the Actions sidebar in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, sidebar, action

Basically I have my Model, View and Controller working perfectly for Users, but I'm trying to find out how and where the "Actions" sidebar gets generated? I'm basically trying to add to it for the Users view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the corresponding view file, e.g. `/views/users/index.ctp`. Remove/edit it there.

Comment: Bah, I didnt notice it was at the bottom of the file! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the code from the view will get rid of the text but the actual sidebar will remain.  To remove that for all views edit webroot/css/cake.generic.css. To modify only a particular view, create your own .css stylesheet and call it from the controller method or view.  [The bakery has helpful article for this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/tulio/2007/01/15/some-ideas-to-organize-your-css-files-and-autoload-them-in-cakephp).